# (Prolog) How do I rearrange elements in the list recursively to give multiple resulting states for an answer?

Tags: list, prolog, definition

'find a list of lists where the first element after first tos() have been moved after each other tos()'.

How do i turn this:

```
[tos(a), 1, 5, 12, tos(b), tos(c), tos(d), 2, 17, tos(e)]
```

Into lists of this using prolog?:

```
 [tos(a), 5, 12, tos(b),1, tos(c), tos(d), 2, 17, tos(e)]
 [tos(a), 5, 12, tos(b), tos(c),1, tos(d), 2, 17, tos(e)]
 [tos(a), 5, 12, tos(b), tos(c), tos(d),1, 2, 17, tos(e)]
 [tos(a), 5, 12, tos(b), tos(c), tos(d), 2, 17, tos(e),1]
```

aka,

```
neighbours([tos(a), 1, 5, 12, tos(b), tos(c), tos(d), 2, 17, tos(e)],X).

X=[[tos(a), 5, 12, tos(b),1, tos(c), tos(d), 2, 17, tos(e)],
 [tos(a), 5, 12, tos(b), tos(c),1, tos(d), 2, 17, tos(e)],
 [tos(a), 5, 12, tos(b), tos(c), tos(d),1, 2, 17, tos(e)],
 [tos(a), 5, 12, tos(b), tos(c), tos(d), 2, 17, tos(e),1]].
```

*edit*Thanks to CapelliC for clarifying my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's an irregular pattern, then you should be more explicit about what you want.

When you explicit it you could find that's easy to program. I assume a description could be

'find a list of lists where the first element after first tos(*) have been moved after each other tos(*)', that is

```
neighbours(P, L) :-
    P = [tos(X),N|Ps],
    findall(Q, move_after(Ps, N, Q), Qs),
    L = [tos(X)|Qs].

move_after([tos(X)|R], N, [tos(X), N|R]).
move_after([E|R], N, [E|S]) :-
    move_after(R, N, S).
```

*edit* since the 'example' you have shown is not valid Prolog syntax, I assumed it was something like

```
X=[[tos(a), 5, 12, tos(b),1, tos(c), tos(d), 2, 17, tos(e)],
 [tos(a), 5, 12, tos(b), tos(c),1, tos(d), 2, 17, tos(e)],
 [tos(a), 5, 12, tos(b), tos(c), tos(d),1, 2, 17, tos(e)],
 [tos(a), 5, 12, tos(b), tos(c), tos(d), 2, 17, tos(e),1]].
```

note the list of lists. But a simpler definition allows to solve in cleaner way:

```
neighbours([tos(X),N|Ps], [tos(X)|Qs]) :-
    move_after(Ps, N, Qs).
```

move_after/3 it's the same as above, but now alternative solutions must be requested by backtracking:

```
?- neighbours([tos(a), 1, 5, 12, tos(b), tos(c), tos(d), 2, 17, tos(e)],L).
L = [tos(a), 5, 12, tos(b), 1, tos(c), tos(d), 2, 17|...] ;
L = [tos(a), 5, 12, tos(b), tos(c), 1, tos(d), 2, 17|...] ;
L = [tos(a), 5, 12, tos(b), tos(c), tos(d), 1, 2, 17|...] ;
L = [tos(a), 5, 12, tos(b), tos(c), tos(d), 2, 17, tos(...)|...] ;
false.
```

note the semicolon, to force backtracking...